# Question about sum of interior angles from two polygons

Tags: geometry

The interior angle of a regular M-gon and the interior angle of a regular N-gon sum to 300 degrees. If M<N, there are four combinations of M and N for which this is true. Give the four possible values of M.

I've tried solving this problem, but am having a lot of difficulty. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you know about the interior angles of a regular polygon?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to know is that the interior angle of a regular n-gon is $\frac{\pi(n-2)}{n}$ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Angles)). After plugging in this expression in the constraint given (and after some simplification), it boils down to this

$MN = 6(M+N)$.

Dividing by $MN$ throughout,

$\frac{1}{M} + \frac{1}{N} = \frac{1}{6}$. As $M<N$, it must be the case that $M<12$; as otherwise $\frac{1}{M}<\frac{1}{12}$ and hence $\frac{1}{N}>\frac{1}{12}$ which is a contradiction to $M<N$.

It is now easy to see the positive integral solutions of this equation (for which $M<N$), $(M,N) = (7,42), (8,24), (9,18), (10,15)$.

Comment: How about $(7,42)$? I think you need to elaborate the last `It is easy to see` step some more.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I missed it. Actually, I did a random trial-and-error check to find the positive integral solutions. Need to improve upon my formal methods.

Comment: That doesn't really constitute a proof, does it. But you are almost there, so why not finish it off. Hint: show that $M \le 12$ (in fact $M \lt 12$ if you assume the strict inequality $M \lt N$ as asked), then check the factors.

Comment: @dxiv - thanks a lot!